# Order of Key Columns in Index

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning, clustered-index

The execution plan for this query appears to be making a very bad choice (of course I know it is not):

```
SELECT TOP 1 E_PER_ID FROM E WHERE E_CUS_ID = 1912 AND E_TYPE = 'R' ORDER BY E_ID DESC
```

The two relevant indexes are:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_EMAIL_2 ON EMAIL
(E_CUS_ID ASC, E_DATE_SENT ASC)
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 95)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_EMAIL_3 ON EMAIL
(E_ID ASC, E_TYPE ASC, E_CUS_ID ASC)
INCLUDE (E_PER_ID)
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 95)
```

The query plan is choosing IX_EMAIL_2.

It appears IX_EMAIL_3 is covering and IX_EMAIL_2 is clearly not.

Is this simply b/c the E_CUS_ID key column is first in IX_EMAIL_2?

I wasn't aware a completely covering index would be ignored by the engine in favor of an index w/ only one of the needed columns but that column was first in the index.

NOTE: This table has 121M records so I can't do much testing to see if I'm right without waiting many hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`E_ID` is not part of the `WHERE` clause while index `IX_EMAIL_3` is sorted by `E_ID` so SQL can't seek to any of value from where and need to scan the index to find it. That is why it is taking `IX_EMAIL_2`.

Try this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_EMAIL_4 ON EMAIL
(E_CUS_ID ASC, E_TYPE ASC, E_ID ASC)
INCLUDE (E_PER_ID)
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 95)
```

I think it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's about your WHERE clause. I guess it takes less IOs to seek an E_CUS_ID ASC and than to perform a lookup to the clustered index getting missed columns and sorting it BY E_ID DESC as scanning the entire 2nd index for E_CUS_ID = 1912 AND E_TYPE = 'R'.